# Unable to get API key after signing up

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I never get an API key. No matter if I sign up with my github account le Microsoft account. I am looking for an emotion API key

Comment: I have had the same problem. I signed up on Friday but I still can't seem to access the keys? I also signed up with Github account.

Comment: Have you verified your email address on the free subscriptions page?  Can you provide the steps you are taking?

Comment: I tried adding the subscription again and it worked. This time I only chose one service.. not sure if that helped.

Comment: I have used Github account and also Microsoft account. I am only choosing one service. Nothing. I am outside US West area, is it relevant??